# XML to Object in AS3

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, object

I'm trying to make this XML file into an object in AS3.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mimeTypes>
    <mimeType>
        <ext>.ico</ext>
        <type>image/x-icon</type>
    </mimeType>
    <mimeType>
        <ext>.txt</ext>
        <type>text/plain</type>
    </mimeType>
    <mimeType>
        <ext>.html</ext>
        <type>text/html</type>
    </mimeType>
</mimeTypes>
```

The problem is I'm trying to make the ext = the type.
For example;

```
mimeTypes[".ico"] = "image/x-icon";
mimeTypes[".txt"] = "text/plain";
mimeTypes[".html"] = "text/html";
```

Is there anyway I can do this?

This is my code right now:

```
var mimeXML = new XML(e.target.data);
var len:uint = mimeXML.mimeType.length();
mimeT[mimeXML.mimeType.child("ext")] = mimeXML.mimeType.child("type");
for(var id:String in mimeT) {
    var value:Object = mimeT[id];
    trace(id + " = " + value);
}
```

but, it outputs:

```
<ext>.ico</ext>
<ext>.txt</ext>
<ext>.html</ext> = <type>image/x-icon</type>
<type>text/plain</type>
<type>text/html</type>
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mimeTypes[String(myXMLNode)] = myXMLNode;

in your case:

```
var xml:XML = 
<mimeTypes>
    <mimeType>
        <ext>ico</ext>
        <type>image/x-icon</type>
    </mimeType>
    <mimeType>
        <ext>txt</ext>
        <type>text/plain</type>
    </mimeType>
    <mimeType>
        <ext>html</ext>
        <type>text/html</type>
    </mimeType>
</mimeTypes>

var myObject:Object = new Object;
for(var i:int = 0; i < xml.mimeType.length(); i++)
{
    var type:Object = new Object;
    type[String(xml.mimeType[i].ext)] = xml.mimeType[i].type;
    myObject[String(xml.mimeType[i].ext)] = type;
    trace(type[String(xml.mimeType[i].ext)]);
}
```

but you will have to remove the dot from the ext node. it wont work with it...

Comment: It doesn't seem to work, it outputs the same as before. I need it so more mimeTypes can be added in the XML file, and have the ext equal the type.

Comment: var mimetypes:Object = new Object(); is your object you can create a danymic property on objects by casting them as String. So, myObject[String(myXMLNode)] = myXMLNode Where myXMLNode is the property name in the object and you assign it to the contents of the node.

Comment: mimeTypes[String(mimeXML.mimeType.child("ext"))] = mimeXML.mimeType.child("type"); ?

Comment: Yes I have, it outputs <ext>.ico</ext>
<ext>.txt</ext>
<ext>.html</ext> = <type>image/x-icon</type>
<type>text/plain</type>
<type>text/html</type>, the .html equals all three of the types, I want the exts to equal their own types.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using e4x to get the XML?  That would return an object structure that's easily traversed and manipulated.

Comment: I'm not sure how I would do this. I just need a simple way to put the ext value with the type value.